# Verify if the email already exists - Shell Script

Tags: shell

```
if [ -f users.txt ];
  a=$(cat users.txt | grep "$email" | cut -d ',' -f1 )
  then
    if [ $a -eq $email ];
      then
        echo " Your email is already registed"
        ./new_user.sh
    fi
fi
```

I have a file called `users.txt` that contains the list of all users, where the email is in the first column, and I want to verify if the email already exists... can someone help me ?

For the first time that I create a user, the file `users.txt` doesn't exist, that's why I'm doing `if [ -f users.txt ];`

Comment: so what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: ./new_user.sh: line15: [: (the repeted email) : integer expression expected 

////
line 15 is " if [ $a -eq $email ];  "

Comment: please do not comment the edits you have in the question. should always do in the main thread. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `if` iss wrong. The correct syntax is

```
if [ condition ]
then
   body
fi
```

so `a=$(cat users.txt | grep "$email" | cut -d ',' -f1 )` cannot be where you have written.

now if you want to check the presence of  `$email` in `users.txt` the `grep` is only required. The second if can be rewritten

```
if [ -f users.txt ];
  grep  -q "$email" users.txt
  if (( $? == 0 ))
  then
        echo " Your email is already registed"
        ./new_user.sh
  fi

 fi
```

What it does??

`grep  -q "$email" users.txt` matches `$email` in `users.txt` file `-q` is quiet so the matched lines are not printed.

`$?` is the exit status of previous command, here the `grep` will have value `0` on successfull completion, that is when there is a match.